# Client closed connection while waiting for request In supervisord when trying to log with monolog in Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, docker, nginx, supervisord

Im trying to show the php-fpm7 logs into the stdout running through nginx and supervisord. The supervisord stdout showed the following message:

```
web_1| 2019-11-22 21:52:30,742 DEBG 'nginx' stdout output:
web_1| 2019/11/22 21:52:30 [info] 10#10: *1 client closed connection while waiting for request, client: 10.11.12.13, server: 0.0.0.0:80
web_1| 2019-11-22 21:52:31,481 BLAT read event caused by <POutputDispatcher at 140523539721320 for <Subprocess at 140523539815888 with name nginx in state RUNNING> (stdout)>
web_1| 10.11.12.13 - - [22/Nov/2019:21:52:31 +0000] "GET /offers/all HTTP/1.1" 500 24984 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.19.0"
```

Nothing is shown in the terminal, but the service answered the request with data.

Here is my configuration:

**docker-compose-dev.yml**

```
services:
  # web server
  web:
    build: .
    working_dir: /app
    network_mode: bridge
    command: supervisord
    [...]
```

**dockerfile**

```
FROM alpine

RUN apk update && \
    apk add bash curl openssh git supervisor nginx php7 \
    [...other dependencies...]

COPY ./config/supervisord.conf /etc
COPY ./config/supervisor-lemp.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/

RUN mkdir -p /var/log/supervisor/

# Nginx configuration
COPY ./config/default /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
COPY ./config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/

# PHP7 Configuration
COPY ./config/www.conf /etc/php7/php-fpm.d/www.conf

# Mount Source code
COPY ./src /app
WORKDIR /app

# permission needed by lumen
RUN chmod -R 777 /app/storage/

RUN composer -v install

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["supervisord"]
```

**supervisord.conf**

```
[...]
[supervisord]
logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log ; (main log file;default $CWD/supervisord.log)
pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid ; (supervisord pidfile;default supervisord.pid)
childlogdir=/var/log/supervisor ; ('AUTO' child log dir, default $TEMP)
nodaemon=true
loglevel=blather
[...]
```

**supervisor-lemp.conf**

```
[program:nginx]
command=nginx
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0

[program:php-fpm7]
command=php-fpm7 --nodaemonize
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
```

**nginx.conf**

```
http {
    [...]
    access_log /dev/stdout;
    error_log /dev/stdout info;
    [...]
}
```

**logging.php** (src/config)

```php
<?php
use Monolog\Formatter\JsonFormatter;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;

return [
    'default' => env('LOG_CHANNEL', 'single'),

    'channels' => [
        'single' => [
            'driver' => 'monolog',
            'name' => 'offer-service-log',
            'handler' => StreamHandler::class,
            'formatter' => JsonFormatter::class,
            'with' => [
                // 'stream' => storage_path('logs/lumen.log'),
                'stream' => 'php://stdout',
            ],
        ],
        'stdout' => [
            'driver' => 'monolog',
            'handler' => StreamHandler::class,
            'formatter' => JsonFormatter::class,
            'with' => [
                'stream' => 'php://stdout',
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

**OfferController.php**

```php
public function all(Request $request): JsonResponse
{
    Log::emergency('Im a log entry');

    throw new Exception("Hello");
    // [...]
}
```

The way I start the container is using `docker-compose` this way:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-dev.yml up --build
```

I can't understand what is happening and figure out how to diagnose the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the problem is on one *.php files which throw an exception when calling it therefore the message : `client closed connection while waiting for request`

Comment: the php file is a lumen controller, if I log to the default `storage/logs/lumen.log` file through monolog, all the `Log:info(...)` content is correctly added to the file.

Comment: Can you share more of your docker file (CMD is what I'm looking for specifically) and the CLI command you're using to start the container?

Comment: @developerjack I updated the question with your request :)